# Find out the local maxima/minima of $\sin x$ where $x\in\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Find out the local maxima/minima of $\sin x$ where $x\in\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$f'(x)=\cos x$$

So getting local minima/maxima at endpoints, is it fine to declare endpoints as minima/maxima?

Comment: Yes, extrema at endpoints are fine.

Comment: Over a closed interval (which you have; that is what the square brackets mean) the endpoints can be the absolute max / min.  Furthermore, over a closed interval, always check the endpoints, as it could be the case that the endpoints are the max / min, but the derivative at these points is not 0.

Comment: no I am not talking about global maxima/global minima, I mean to say local minima/local maxima.

Comment: If we’re being picky, depending on your definition of derivative it might not even exist at the endpoints of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also look at the sign of the second derivative in those points to establish if they are local minima or maxima points.

However, there is no need for derivatives if you just know the graph of $\sin x$. It's pretty clear that $\sin $ is decreasing over $\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$, so:

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{2} \geq \sin x \geq \sin \frac{3\pi}{2}\Rightarrow 1\geq \sin x\geq -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a derivative, note that $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$, with it being $-1$ at $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ and $1$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, the local minima/maxima of $\sin(x)$ with $x \in\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$ are $-1$ and $1$, respectively.

As for using extrema at the end points, as [shortmanikos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/729993/shortmanikos)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547089/find-out-the-local-maxima-minima-of-sin-x-where-x-in-left-dfrac-pi2-df#comment7294150_3547089) and [Doug M](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317162/doug-m)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547089/find-out-the-local-maxima-minima-of-sin-x-where-x-in-left-dfrac-pi2-df#comment7294151_3547089) state, it's fine since you have a closed interval of $\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$, but be careful if using the derivative as it may not necessarily be $0$ at those points.